# BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash in SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

I've tried looking at previous questions and answers regarding this error, but the solutions didn't seem to work for me. The error is thrown on the line:

```
if customer && customer.authenticate(params[:session][:password_digest])
```

I am able to Sign Up a user (under a company) and sign up a company, but I get this BCrypt error whenever I try to log a user in. I only started using the has_secure_password stuff etc once my user model and company model etc. were in place, I just realised later that it was silly to not protect passwords. 
Even if I create a new user now, I still get this error logging on.

I think this might be due to my relationships of my Users? (maybe completely not, I am very new to Ruby!) My users belong to a company (many to one), and when they sign up they choose a company from a list in order to be listed under it in the database. Here is my code relating to this error:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end

  def create
    customer = Customer.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if customer && customer.authenticate(params[:session][:password_digest])
      log_in customer #see sessions helper
      remember customer #see sessions helper
      redirect_to '/main'
    else
      redirect_to '/login'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    #session[:user_id] = nil
    forget(current_customer)
    session.delete(:customer_id)
    @current_customer = nil
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end



class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :customers do |t|
      t.timestamps
      t.references :business, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name

      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :remember_digest
      t.string :role
    end
  end
end


class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new
    @businesses = Business.all
  end

  def create
    @customer = Customer.create(customer_params)
    @customer.save!
    session[:customer_id] = @customer.id
    redirect_to '/'
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => ex
    render action: 'new', alert: ex.message
  end

  private
  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :business_no, :email, :password_digest, :business_id) #replace company with company ID
  end
end
```

Please help me, I'm tearing my hair out :(

Comment: May or may not be relevant but you should be calling `authenticate` with the plain text password rather than the `password_digest`. So `if customer && customer.authenticate(params[:session][:password])`. [Source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Does it matter if i've only defined the password_digest in the user migrate? If it doesn't, do I do that by changing the log in form password fill in symbol to :password rather than :password_digest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're getting probably means that the `password_digest` stored for that user is invalid for some reason (empty perhaps).
Enter a rails console: `rails console`
and execute the following:

```
u = User.find_by(email: "your_user_email")
puts u.password_digest
```

and see what the output is.

(also as mentioned in a comment on your question, you should use the plain text password when you use the authenticate method)

### Update

You shouldn't use the `password_digest` attribute directly, instead there are two attributes you should be using: `password` and `password_confirmation` (these attributes become available to you automatically when you use `has_secure_password`, so you don't need to define them).

So in your controller, instead of this:

```
params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :business_no, :email, :password_digest, :business_id) #replace company with company ID
```

You should have:

```
params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :business_no, :email, :password, :password_confirmation :business_id) #replace company with company ID
```

and edit your form accordingly to provide inputs for `password` and `password_confirmation`.

Now when you create your object using these params, it will automatically assign the password digest into `password_digest` by encrypting the clear text contained in `password` and `password_confirmation`.

Comment: ok, I am very confused. Could you explain to me why this is happening? c = Customer.find_by(email: "sarahcraig1994@yahoo.com")
  Customer Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers"  WHERE "customers"."email" = 'sarahcraig1994@yahoo.com' LIMIT 1
#<Customer id: 1, created_at: "2015-11-24 14:44:38", updated_at: "2015-11-24 14:44:38", business_id: 2, first_name: "sarah", last_name: "craig", email: "sarahcraig1994@yahoo.com", password_digest: "password", remember_digest: nil, role: nil>
>> puts c.password_digest
password
nil

Comment: why is it returning both "password" (the password I signed up with) and 'nil'?

Comment: Don't worry about the `nil`, the `puts` method always returns `nil`.

Comment: Now, your problem is that your `password_digest` equals `password` and that's not a valid password hash, this is the reason you get the error. 
`Bcrypt` expects `password_digest` to be a valid digest, not a clear text.
In other words the value for `password_digest` is supposed to be a long encrypted string. How are you storing the password for you model?

Comment: glad I could help, please mark the answer as correct.